# Proof of the Lebesgue Covering Dimension of a Menger Sponge

Tags: general-topology, fractals, dimension-theory-analysis

I've recently been doing some research into the Menger sponge and there is constant mention (without reference) of the sponge having a covering dimension of 1. Does anybody have a proof of this or know where I could find one?

Comment: Did you try to do it yourself? If you did not, I suggest you try first the square Sierpinski carpet and see if you can prove that its dimension is $\le 1$ (the lower bound $1$ is clear). If you manage, then try the Menger curve.

Comment: Thanks, but I was more hoping to find a reasonably short pre-existing proof.

Comment: Having said that, I've just had a think about it for the Sierpinski carpet and I'm pretty sure I've got a solution that might work for the Menger sponge too. Cheers.

Comment: Good! By doing such things yourself you typically learn much more than reading somebody else's proof.